# Inconsistent MediaConnection behaviour, some files don't show in Android File Transfer

Tags: android, android-mediascanner

I have a directory structure of files in external storage. They don't show up in the Android File Transfer app, so I think it's a media scanner problem.

I'm creating them with a `FileOutputStream` in a directory based on `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)`.

I have the following method, called from an activity, so `context` is an activity (forget that this blocks the main thread for now!):

```
 public void scan(Context context, File base) {
        File[] files = base.listFiles();
        if (files == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{path}, null, null);
                    Log.e("Langstroth", path);
                } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    this.scan(context, file);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void scan(Context context) {
        this.scan(context, this.baseDir);
    }
}
```

The output of the log is as expected:

```
E/MyApp﹕ /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Langstroth/sample/5000/1430576404874.wav
E/MyApp﹕ /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Langstroth/sample/5000/1430577209491.wav
```

And then lots of:

```
E/MyApp﹕ Scan completed path /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Langstroth/sample/5000/1430576404874.wav uri content://media/external/audio/media/7836
E/MyApp﹕ Scan completed path /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Langstroth/sample/5000/1430577209491.wav uri content://media/external/audio/media/7838
```

This proves that the files exist. They don't show up in the Android File Transfer though.

Here's the strange thing. Another method:

```
 public void otherDemo(Context context, File baseDir) {
            String newPath = baseDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/some/random/dirs";
        Log.e("Langstroth", "New path " + newPath);

        File dir = new File(newPath);
        dir.mkdirs();

        Log.e("Langstroth", dir.exists() ? "Dir exists": "Dir does not exist");

        File f = new File(dir, "myfile.txt");

        try {
            new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f)).close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.e("Langstroth", f.exists() ? "File exists": "File does not exist");

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{f.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);
    }
```

and the log output:

```
E/MyApp﹕ New path /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Langstroth/some/random/other/dirs
E/MyApp﹕ Dir exists
E/MyApp﹕ File exists
E/MyApp﹕ File: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Langstroth/some/random/other/dirs/myfile.txt
E/MyApp﹕ Other scan completed path /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Langstroth/some/random/other/dirs/myfile.txt uri content://media/external/file/7842
```

**One test file shows up, the others don't**

Proof:

[image: proof]

Where are the other files?

Comment: Be sure to call `getFD().sync()` on your `FileOutputStream` before closing it, to ensure all bytes are flushed to disk, before you try scanning the file.

Comment: I had assumed that it was auto-flushing, so I hadn't done that. Thanks, that seems to fix it! I'm curious though, the files shows up in a `.listFiles()`, and `.exist()`, and the callback for the `MediaScanner` says that it completed correctly. Surely an extant (if empty) file should show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, before you let another process work with a file, you want to ensure all bytes are flushed to disk, via `getFD().sync()`. In particular, this seems to help with the whole media scanning thing.

> the files shows up in a .listFiles(), and .exist(), and the callback for the MediaScanner says that it completed correctly. Surely an extant (if empty) file should show up?

The ways of the media scanner are mysterious. :-) IOW, beats me.

Bear in mind that there are multiple moving parts here: your app, the media scanner, the MTP daemon on Android, and your MTP client. The breakdown could be at any stage. If you unplug and re-plug in the device, and now the files show up in your MTP client, my guess would be that the MTP client is working off of a slightly stale cache.